# Trying to Get a Twitter Bot to Tweet Two Images at Once

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, twitter, bots

I'm working on a twitter bot that has the goal of posting two images along with a string of text. I'm using node.js (for the first time, I should probably add) and [the Twit package](https://github.com/ttezel/twit).

I'm having a variety of issues, many of which are likely just due to me being a novice, but I genuinely can't figure out how to make the dang thing output correctly. I've managed to get text and a single image to output, but I'm trying to spit out two images at once.

The main bot chunk uses the following code to build and schedule a tweet:

```
function mainPostBot() {
console.log("Now assembling a new tweet.");

var leftCard = getRandomNumber(1, 36);
    console.log("The left card is #" + leftCard + ", " + cardNames[leftCard] + ".");
    // Generates a random number for the left card.
var leftImagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/leftImage/' + imageArray[leftCard]);
    console.log("The left image's path is " + leftImagePath);
    // Gives the file path to access the correct image for the left.

var rightCard = getRandomNumber(1, 36);
    console.log("The right card is #" + rightCard + ", " + cardNames[rightCard] + ".");
    // Generates a random number for the right card.
while (leftCard == rightCard) {
    var rightCard = getRandomNumber(1, 36);
    console.log("Whoops! The right card is now #" + rightCard + ", " + cardNames[rightCard] + ".");
    // Generates a random number for the right card in the case of doubles.
}
var rightImagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/rightImage/' + imageArray[rightCard]);
    console.log("The right image's path is " + rightImagePath);
    // Gives the file path to access the correct image for the left.

console.log('Encoding the images...');
    var b64contentLeft = fs.readFileSync(leftImagePath, { encoding: 'base64' });
    var b64contentRight = fs.readFileSync(rightImagePath, { encoding: 'base64' });
    var bothImages = (b64contentLeft + "," + b64contentRight);
    // This encodes the images in base64, which twitter needs. I guess. I dunno, man.

var tweetText = (jsUcfirst(cardNames[leftCard]) + ' and ' + cardNames[rightCard] + '. (#' + leftCard + " " + cardCorrespond[leftCard] + "/#" + rightCard + " " + cardCorrespond[rightCard] + ")");
// This constructs the grammar of the tweet.
// jsUcfirst capitalizes the first letter of a string so it lets me cheat a sentence start.

var tweetTime = getRandomNumber(1000*60*60*4, 1000*60*60*24*3+1);
    // Generates an amount of time before the next tweet.

sendTweet(tweetText, bothImages, tweetTime);

setTimeout(mainPostBot, tweetTime);
}

mainPostBot();
```

cardNames, cardCorrespond, and imageArray are just big arrays at the top of the program that list the names of the images, some info about them, and their filenames, respectively:

```
var cardNames = new Array(
    "the Fool", //This one will never be called bc of the number generator and it's fun bc, y'know, Tarot
    "the Rider","the Clover","the Ship","the House","the Tree","the Clouds","the Snake","the Coffin","the Bouquet","the Scythe","the Whip", //"the Nae Nae",
    "the Birds","the Child","the Fox","the Bear","the Stars","the Stork","the Dog","the Tower","the Garden","the Mountain","the Crossroads",
    "the Mice","the Heart","the Ring","the Book","the Letter","the Gentleman","the Lady","the Lily","the Sun","the Moon","the Key","the Fish",
    "the Anchor","the Cross"
    );

var cardCorrespond = new Array(
    " ","9♥","6♦","10♠","K♥","7♥","K♣","Q♣","9♦","Q♠","J♦","J♣","7♦","J♠","9♣","10♣","6♥","Q♥","10♥",
    "6♠","8♠","8♣","Q♦","7♣","J♥","A♣","10♦","7♠","A♥","A♠","K♠","A♦","8♥","8♦","K♦","9♠","6♣"
    );

var imageArray = new Array(
    " ","01.png","02.png","03.png","04.png","05.png","06.png","07.png","08.png","09.png","10.png","11.png","12.png","13.png",
    "14.png","15.png","16.png","17.png","18.png","19.png","20.png","21.png","22.png","23.png","24.png","25.png","26.png",
    "27.png","28.png","29.png","30.png","31.png","32.png","33.png","34.png","35.png","36.png"
    );
```

And once mainPostBot has the tweet fully constructed, it's delivered to sendTweet:

```
function sendTweet(text, images, time){

    console.log('Uploading the images...');

    T.post('media/upload', { media_data: images }, function (err, data, response){
        if (err){
            console.log("There's an issue uploading the images.");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Images uploaded!');
            console.log("Now tweeting...")

            T.post('statuses/update', {
                status: text,
                media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
            }, function(err, data, response){
                if (err) {
                    console.log("An error has occurred during posting.");
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Post successful!");
                    console.log("The tweet says:" + text);
                    console.log("The next tweet will send in " + msToTime(time) + "!");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas? I'm open to using other npm packages, for sure, but I just can't figure out why this doesn't work as it is. Thanks for reading, and let me know if you need any other bits of the code.

EDIT 1: My roommate who also dabbles in this sort of stuff found a potentially [useful link on github](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/issues/54) for another package, node-twitter. In that link, a poster explains that the images should be delivered as a string, separated by commas, so I added some edits to mainPostBot and sendTweet, mostly in the passing of b64 image data.

EDIT 2: Those edits are now reflected in the code above, as well as some other fixes I've made to the project as a whole. I got to a point where things are running smoothly again (found a missing bracket, I suck at this coding stuff), and there's tweets posting successfully, but just as before I'm not getting the second image through. Roommate who helped earlier is suggesting to just pump out static single images for every possible card combination but there's gotta be a more elegant solution. Again, any ideas could save a week of my weird bedroom tinkering, and I appreciate any eyes on this.

Answer (score 1):

It took a lot of tinkering, but I figured it out. Each image has to be uploaded to twitter individually, so after loading the image, I save it's data.media_id_string to a variable, and then load those values into the tweet in an array.

I've removed the line from mainPostBot where I combined b64contentLeft and b64contentRight and added it into the sendTweet code, using the returned data strings. Now, I call sendTweet() with:

```
sendTweet(tweetText, b64contentLeft, b64contentRight, tweetTime);
```

And sendTweet() is now looking like this:

```
function sendTweet(text, leftimage, rightimage, time){

    console.log('Uploading the images...');

    T.post('media/upload', { media_data: leftimage }, function (err, data, response){
        if (err){
            console.log("There's an issue uploading the left image.");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Left image uploaded!');
            var leftID = data.media_id_string;

            T.post('media/upload', { media_data: rightimage }, function (err, data, response){
                if (err){
                    console.log("There's an issue uploading the right image.");
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Right image uploaded!');
                    var rightID = data.media_id_string;
                    var bothImages = ( leftID + "," + rightID );

                    console.log("Now tweeting...")

                    T.post('statuses/update', {
                        status: text,
                        media_ids: new Array(bothImages)
                    }, function(err, data, response){
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("An error has occurred during posting.");
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Post successful!");
                            console.log("The tweet says: " + text);
                            console.log("The next tweet will send in " + msToTime(time) + "!");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Essentially, if the left image uploads correctly, it'll save that ID, then try for the right image. IF that's successful, it'll save that ID as well, then combine the two into a string separated with a comma, which is loaded into the media_ids array as bothImages.

This was kind of a nightmare to solve, but I wanted to make sure it's documented in case anyone else stumbles here looking for the same answer.